# ¿Como leer una columna vacio de excel en java?

Tags: java

Buen dia amigos, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, lo que pasa es que tengo un archivo de excel que lo estoy procesando desde java y en modo debug esto es lo que se presenta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: La cuenta que sale como 7.0000193E7 vendría siendo 70000193, ese como tal ya mas adelante cuando fluye el proceso lo arregla.

Como se puede apreciar no se está tomando en cuenta una columna (lo que está marcado en azul), el archivo que estoy procesando es lo que tiene como contenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna que está marcado es la que no me lo está tomando en cuenta y el 620 es el que toma su lugar al momento de procesar la información, la duda es, como puedo hacer que lo tome como una columna mas y se vea algo asi:

```
[R07,   70000193,   GPT9309082R4,   ,"",    620]
```

El código java es el siguiente:

```
private HSSFWorkbook abrirLibro(InputStream archivo) {
    try {
        HSSFWorkbook libro = new HSSFWorkbook(archivo);
        LOG.info("Se abrio el libro");
        return libro;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (archivo != null) {
            try {
                archivo.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

private Vector<Vector<Cell>> leerArchivoExcel(HSSFWorkbook archivo) {
    Vector<Vector<Cell>> cellVectorHolder = new Vector<Vector<Cell>>();
    try {
        HSSFSheet mySheet = archivo.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
            Row myRow = rowIter.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
            Vector<Cell> cellStoreVector = new Vector<Cell>();
            while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
                Cell myCell = cellIter.next();
                cellStoreVector.addElement(myCell);
            }
            cellVectorHolder.addElement(cellStoreVector);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return cellVectorHolder;
}

private boolean vectorVacio(Vector<Cell> cellStoreVector){
    if(cellStoreVector == null)
        return true;
    for(Cell cell : cellStoreVector){
        if(cell!=null){
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        }else{
            continue;
        }
        if(!cell.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Espero brindar su ayuda por favor, si hay algo que no se entienda con gusto lo aclararé, de ante mano gracias y quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios. Gracias.

Comment: Hola @JaimeMenéndez ya metí la validación, pero no funcionó, lo de la parte cellStoreVector.addElement("");----> No funcionó ya que me salió este mensaje "The method addElement(Cell) in the type Vector<Cell> is not applicable for the arguments (String)" y probé "cellStoreVector.addElement(null);" pero tampoco entró, toda la validación fue así:    if(myCell==null) {
      cellStoreVector.addElement(null);
     }else {
      cellStoreVector.addElement(myCell); 
     }

Comment: Disculpa, solo miré el código y ahora me fijo en el debugger que desde que te llega al método te llega sin la columna. Leyendo tu código veo la causa, y es que `rowIterator` y `cellIterator` según la [documentación oficial](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator), se salta los campos vacíos: _"Note that a rowIterator and cellIterator iterate over rows or cells that have been created, **skipping empty rows and cells**."_. Justo en ese link te dan un ejemplo para el tratamiento de columnas y rows vacíos.

Comment: Hola, comprendo, pero otra cosa que acabo de ver, por que será que si se quita el de la ultima columna que sería el 620, para este caso si lo toma lee como vacio y lo considera nulo? Como tal no tendría que ser iguales?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el iterador devuelve las celdas que tengan algún valor, formato o estilo, pero esto depende del excel. Probablemente la columna del régimen fiscal tenga formato numérico o algo así. _"cellIterator solo devolverá las celdas definidas, que son aquellas con valores o estilos, pero depende de Excel"_. Prueba aplicando un formato a la columna vacía.

Comment: De cualquier manera intenta algo como esto https://pastebin.com/XNtM0Pad.

Comment: Hola, si tienes razón, está involucrando el formato que se le pone, por ejemplo si lo pongo en general no lo toma pero si lo pongo por ejemplo en texto si lo toma en consideración, hay alguna forma de validar esto desde java?

Comment: La forma de validarlo es haciendo la iteración manual, y no usando `cellIterator` como se adjunta en la documentación oficial o en el ejemplo de mi último comentario adaptado a tu donde especifico el mínimo número de columnas a leer.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, estoy revisando lo que me pasaste de este link  pastebin.com/XNtM0Pad ya lo comparé con lo que tengo en mi metodo, pero este enum CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK me arroja el siguiente mensaje: CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK cannot be resolved or is not a field, esa parte en donde mas se coloca o podría ser que por la versión de java que no lo tome en cuenta? Por ejemplo estoy usando java 7

Comment: ¿Importaste `import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;`?

Comment: Si lo importé de echo me lo puso en automatico, pero aún así no lo está tomando en cuenta :(

Comment: Prueba quitando ese segundo argumento. No es necesario. Aunque no se si funcionará como espero, dado que probablemente devuelva null. Debes estar usando una versión realmente antigua, porque hace mucho que solo dan soporte para Java >= 8.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135875/discussion-between-cratus666jose-and-jaime-menendez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que `rowIterator` y `cellIterator` según la [documentación oficial](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator), se salta los campos vacíos:

> *"Note that a rowIterator and cellIterator iterate over rows or cells that have been created, skipping empty rows and cells."*

Y es que los iteradores devuelven solo las celdas que tienen algún valor, formato o estilo, dependiendo del Excel, es por ello que no obtienes las celdas en blanco.

> *"The CellIterator will only return the cells defined in the file, which is largely those with values or stylings, but it depends on Excel"*

Tienes varias soluciones, la primera es, simplemente dar un formato específico a la columna, un formato que no sea el general y tu código funcionará.

La segunda solución es modificar el método `leerArchivoExcel` para que cuando lea cada celda, lo fuerces a leer mínimo las 5 columnas. Para ello debes utilizar un ciclo `for` en lugar de iteradores.

Primero, estableces el mínimo número de columnas a leer, en este caso, mínimo 5:

```
 int lastColumn = Math.max( myRow.getLastCellNum(), 5 );
```

Con un ciclo `for`, vas obteniendo las celdas. Nota que si la celda obtenida es nula, se devolverá una celda en blanco gracias al segundo argumento `Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK`:

```java
for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
    Cell c = myRow.getCell( cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL );
    cellStoreVector.addElement( c );
}
```

El método completo quedaría:

```
private Vector<Vector<Cell>> leerArchivoExcel(HSSFWorkbook archivo) {
    Vector<Vector<Cell>> cellVectorHolder = new Vector<Vector<Cell>>();
    try {
        HSSFSheet mySheet = archivo.getSheetAt( 0 );
        Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
            Row myRow = rowIter.next();
            Vector<Cell> cellStoreVector = new Vector<Cell>();
            int lastColumn = Math.max( myRow.getLastCellNum(), 5 );
            for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
                Cell c = myRow.getCell( cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL );
                cellStoreVector.addElement( c );
            }
            cellVectorHolder.addElement( cellStoreVector );
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error( e.getMessage() );
    }
    return cellVectorHolder;
}
```

Comment: Hola Jaime Melendez. muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvió bastante y con eso solucionó el problema de mi pregunta, espero que alguien mas le sirva esta respuesta. Saludos.